# What is the difference between stack struct vs heap struct?

Tags: c, struct, types, heap-memory, difference

```c
// Define Person 
typedef struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
} person_t;

// Init person in heap
person_t *create_person_v1(char *name, int age)
{
    person_t *person = calloc(1, sizeof(person_t));
    person->name = name;
    person->age = age;
    return person;
}

// Init person on stak? a static struct I guess?
person_t create_person_v2(char *name, int age)
{
    return (person_t) {name, age};
}
```

The code above has a definition of Person and two helper functions for its further initialization.

I don't really understand **the difference** between them, and what are **the benefits** of having each?

Is it something more than just accessors `->` and `.` ?

Comment: Unrelated: you're copying the `name` pointer such that you end up with two ways to access the name (through the original pointer used in the calling code and through the struct). Any change to the `name` through any of these means **will be** reflected when `name` is accessed though the other means. Maybe you want to `malloc()` and `strcpy()` instead?

Comment: `create_person_v1` returns a _pointer_ to a `person_t` whereas `create_person_v2` returns a `person_t`. This is fundamentally different. if you have difficulties to understand this, I strongly suggest you read again the chapter dealing with pointers in your C learning material.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm pretty sure the PO understand what technical differences there are between that, but not functionnal differencies. A lot of courses stop to the first point.

Comment: @pmg Yes, you're right. Can I just destroy the first pointer somehow? Just for a sake

Comment: Funny thing: The standard does know nothing of "stack" or "heap"...

Comment: @DickWilliams: when you destroy the first pointer, the pointer in the struct also gets destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last function does not allocate a static structure, but a structure on the stack. There is two kind of memory for your programm, heap and stack. static is an other keyword (which have more than 1 use, depending on where they are used, but it's not the current subject).

heap allocations use more ressources than stack allocations, but are not tied to scopes where they are used. You can manipulate structures heap allocated between functions without having to think they can be "automatically freed" because the scope on which they are tied disappear (aka : initial function returned).

An example would be a linked list. You can't rely on stack allocations to build a linked list of structures.

Heap allocations can fail, you always have to check if malloc, calloc and cie, does not return NULL.

Stack allocations doesn't fail like that. If you sucked all your stack, your programm will just crash. ( Or do some fancy things, it is undefined bahavior ). But you can't recover from that.

stack allocated memory is "freed" on function returns.
not heap allocated memory. But you have to free it by hand (with function free)